# Http request change delay

Tags: http, ethernet-shield

i'm noob in coding i try to make some led blink ( with succes ) and now i would like to add http request to change delay.

i have no error compiling the code but it dont work any idea ?

Thanks

```
 include SPI.h
 include Ethernet.h

unsigned long maxTime = 4000;


EthernetServer arduinoServer(81);
EthernetServer httpServer(80);

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 8, 60);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(80);

////CODE IS 11001010
int led1 = 6;  // = 0
int led2 = 7;  // = 1 


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Setup the 3 pins as OUTPUT
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);


  // You can use Ethernet.init(pin) to configure the CS pin
  //Ethernet.init(10);  // Most Arduino shields
  //Ethernet.init(5);   // MKR ETH shield
  //Ethernet.init(0);   // Teensy 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(20);  // Teensy++ 2.0
  //Ethernet.init(15);  // ESP8266 with Adafruit Featherwing Ethernet
  //Ethernet.init(33);  // ESP32 with Adafruit Featherwing Ethernet

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.println("Ethernet WebServer Example");

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  // Check for Ethernet hardware present
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
    while (true) {
      delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
    }
  }
  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
  }

  // start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

}

void loop() 
{
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  delay(maxTime);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  delay(maxTime);
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  delay(maxTime);
   digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  delay(maxTime);
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
   delay(maxTime);

   digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  delay(maxTime);
   digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
   digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  delay(maxTime);
   digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  delay(maxTime);
   digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
   digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  delay(maxTime);
   digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  delay(maxTime);
     digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
   digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  delay(5000);



 // listen for incoming clients
}

void receiveHttpRequest() {
  EthernetClient client = httpServer.available();
  String requestInputString;
  boolean resetArduino = false;
  boolean forceSolved = false;
  client.setConnectionTimeout(50);

  if (client)
  {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    boolean firstLine = true;
    requestInputString = String("");
    while (client.connected())
    {
      if (client.available())
      {
        char c = client.read();
        if (firstLine)
        {
          requestInputString += String(c);
        }
        Serial.write(c);
        // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // so you can send a reply
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank)
        {

          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println("Connection: close"); // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
          client.println();
          client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          client.println("<html><body>");

            int newMaxTime = requestInputString.substring(20).toInt();
            if (newMaxTime < 2000) {
              newMaxTime = 2000;
            }

            maxTime = newMaxTime;

            client.print(String("New maxTime is: "));
            client.println(maxTime);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: At no point do you call `receiveHttpRequest()`. Just making a function isn't good enough - you have to actually call that function.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `delay()` no other code can run. Which also means that no clients can be serviced.

Change that delay-laden function to a state machine mirroring blinkWithoutDelay.

That is you test `if(millis() - previousTimestamp < delay)` and if true progress to the next state in your blinks and update `previousTimestamp`.

After that `if` you call `receiveHttpRequest()` to see if any clients are waiting and process the input.